# Can we able to Read the Custom tab label Name in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, custom-tab

I have added two new Custom tab in account page

1. Student
2. Parents 
   ( Both are stored in Contact object mapped to Account)

On click of student tab need to display the students details in data-table, As same as On click of Parents tab need to display the Parents details in data-table.

I trying to achieve this in Single LWC page. if we get the Custom tab label name  will get the record type for the contact and display the record.

My Question is onclick of Custom tab in lightning app builder,will be able to get the tab `label name` in LWC.

Comment: The custom tab you mean the custom tab in lightning app builder?

Comment: Yes Rahul, custom tab in lightning app builder

Comment: Don't use the label - it can be localized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well afaik, you can't get the selected tab, but there is another way. You can use a design attribute here. Let's say `Type`, and you can use the same component in both tabs with different values to the `Type` design attribute.

[Configure a Component for Lightning App Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_app_builder)

You need to define a public attribute for that, like.

```
@api Type
```

Based on the value of Type you can do your logic.

```
if(this.Type === 'Student'){
     // do the logic to fetch the students data
} else if (Type === 'Parents'){
     // do the logic to fetch the parents data.
}
```

Also, you need to make this attribute available to the lightning app builder by defining the below code in lwc's meta XML file.

```
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
        <property name="Type" type="String" datasource="Student,Parents" />
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

Now the Type value you can set directly from app builder. Which looks something like this.

[image]

Comment: Not getting you Rahul, can you please help me to understand on this.

Comment: @SFDC_Beginner I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, For Making me to understand on this :)

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot!